# Receiving input from JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm have a grid of textfields and labels and i want to know what would i have to do to get the input from the textfields. I know how to do it if it was declared? i think is the word for it, but this is a bit different. i dont know how to recieve the input from something that hasnt been given a name. this was something i realized after the matter.

**A sample from a class of what i'm talking about**

```
for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
    p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    p3.setBorder(lineBorder);
    for (int d = 0; d <= 8; d++) {
        if (d == 0) {
            p3.add(new JLabel("5", JLabel.CENTER));
        } else if (d == 5) {
            p3.add(new JLabel("8", JLabel.CENTER));
        } else if (d == 7) {
            p3.add(new JLabel("2", JLabel.CENTER));
        } else {
            p3.add(new JTextField(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a `List` before the `for` loop and change the else statement to

```
else {
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(1);
    list.add(tf);
    p3.add(tf);
}
```

After that iterate over the `list` and get the text from each element.

Comment: ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); right? because the add in list.add(tf); is giving me error

Comment: i get this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField)

Comment: Change `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` to `ArrayList<JTextField> list = new ArrayList<JTextField>();`... you want to add `JTextField` objects and no `String`s ;-)